# Autodesk Forge Viewer getting fragment position

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I'm trying to get the position of separate meshes in a model (translated from a revit file).
What I'm doing is to get fragmentProxy, then use getOriginalWorldMatrix() to get the THREE.Matrix4(). Then from the Matrix4, call getPosition() to get the THREE.Vector3 world position of the fragment.
However, every mesh returns the same position value. Is that because of how the model is built originally? Or I have to get the fragment position using a different method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process of retrieving the fragment transform is correct. Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```js
function getFragmentTransform(model, fragid) {
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    let xform = new THREE.Matrix4();
    frags.getOriginalWorldMatrix(fragid, xform);
    return xform;
}
```

I'm afraid you are correct that, in some cases, the transform may be baked directly into the mesh vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much.
So I'm guessing the position is the same because of how Revit handles position, where all fragment will have the same pivot position, and their position is the pivot?
Is there any way I can get the position of each fragment in the model world space? Maybe converting the Matrix4 world position to local position of each fragment?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Revit so I can't confirm if that's the case but it does look like it. If the world position is already baked into the fragment's vertices (as opposed to being specified in the fragments transform matrix), you could get the "world bounding box" (`fragList.getWorldBounds(fragid, bbox)`) of the fragment and use its center point as the world position.