# Autodesk Forge Viewer get local position of fragment

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm working with Autodesk Viewer v7 trying to get position of fragments in a translated Revit .rvt file. Due to how Revit handles model position, I'm unable to extract the world position of fragments using fragProxy.getWorldMatrix().
So is there a way to get the position of fragment in a translated Revit model? Or if not possible, a way to get local position of the fragment?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749870/autodesk-forge-viewer-getting-fragment-position): if the fragments in your Forge model have the position baked into their vertices (in other words, if each fragment's transform is an identity matrix), you could try computing an *"approximate"* position of each fragment in the world coordinate system by computing the fragment's bounding box, and then retrieving its center point:

```js
function getApproximatePosition(model, fragid) {
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    let bbox = new THREE.Box3();
    frags.getWorldBounds(fragid, bbox);
    return bbox.center();
}
```