# Is it possible to identify interior and exterior elements of a BIM model using Autodesk forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I've been learning Forge API for past few months, but still relatively new to the platform. Please excuse if this is an obvious question.
I have an Autodesk Forge application where I upload a Revit file and extract its meta data into a database. In the metadata, there is a category called 'Function'. It shows if the particular element is Interior or Exterior. If the 'Function' data is missing, is there any possible way to identify an interior and exterior element using the Autodesk forge API? Or programmatically?

In Revit, I use Element.Location node (in Dynamo) and extract XYZ coordinates of walls, windows etc, and run that data through an algorithm which differentiates interior and exterior elements. What is the possible way of identifying interior and exterior walls, windows, stairs etc.

Appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, only Revit walls have the function parameter, and it's part of element properties (in Revit, we call it parameters). In Forge Viewer, you can get it via call [Viewer3D#getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback).

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/RevitLT-ArchDes/files/GUID-718C1341-C4FC-40D6-9646-D2E13A861D33-htm.html

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no equality of Revit API's `Element.Location` in Forge Viewer, since all geometries will be translated to meshes during Forge translation. To get mesh location, you may take advantage of the center of the object bounding box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769854/7745569

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I will try out getting the fragment positions based on the vertices. On another note, I have found some sample Revit files, for which when I extracted the metadata, there were several other elements including floors and windows and doors that had the Function: Interior/Exterior. https://i.imgur.com/0GTkOF2.png Is this data usually tagged while designing the Revit file? If yes, and in case it is not tagged, will finding the fragment position help in determining if the element is interior or exterior? Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I didn't notice that Floor has the `function` parameter. It should depend on the designer. The function parameter might not be set up with the proper value. https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-AE45EE40-0B20-4638-A122-26A3E023CC27 and https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-718C1341-C4FC-40D6-9646-D2E13A861D33

Comment: It would be hard to determine Interior/Exterior elements in the viewer if the function parameters don't have been set up properly. So, I would advise you to consider using the Revit API instead, and run it on the Desisgn Automation API for Revit. Here is a discussion of Revit API on finding exterior walls: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/05/filterrule-use-and-retrieving-exterior-walls.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that suggestion. Running Revit API through design automation helped solve my problem. However, it only identifies and differentiates walls, windows and doors from interior and exterior. If a BIM model has MEP components, is there a possible way to identify MEP elements from exterior and interior? Please suggest and advice how can I achieve it.